# RAW icmp socket : How to have correct reply

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to build a simple icmp echo request, but I'm not able to have good reply.

I tried to send a request with a RAW socket and with protocol IPPROTO_ICMP or IPPROTO_RAW and I am getting different results, from no reply it all to a reply with an icmp type 69 or a type 8.

```
ctx.socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW); // OR IPPROTO_ICMP
if (ctx.socket_fd == -1)
{
    perror("socket:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int on = 1;
setsockopt(ctx.socket_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on)); // IF IPPROTO_ICMP and struct ip not sent
```

First initialisation :

```
    struct s_ping       packet = {
    .ip = { // == struct ip if IPPROTO_RAW or if setsockoptionned IP_HDRINCL
        .ip_hl = BYTE_TO_WORD(sizeof(struct iphdr)),
        .ip_v = 4,
        /* tos */
        .ip_len = htons(sizeof(packet)),
        .ip_id = (u_short)getpid(),
        .ip_off = htons(IP_DF),
        .ip_ttl = TTL,
        .ip_p = IPPROTO_ICMP,
    },
    .icmp = { // == struct icmp
        .icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO,
        .icmp_code = 0,
        .icmp_id = (u_int16_t)getpid(),
    },
};
memset(&packet.icmp.icmp_data, 0, DATA_LEN);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &packet.ip.ip_src.s_addr);
inet_pton(AF_INET, ctx->addr /* == "127.0.0.1", &packet.ip.ip_dst.s_addr);
```

And then last icmp datas :

```
packet.icmp.icmp_seq = htons(sequence);
packet.icmp.icmp_cksum = 0;
packet.icmp.icmp_cksum = htons(checksum(&packet, sizeof(packet)));
```

For IPPROTO_RAW the data is sent but there is no reply back it all
For IPPROTO_ICMP with the HDRINCL I have a reply with an icmp ECHO (type 8), not an echo_reply(type 1)
For IPPROTO_ICMP without HDRINCL ( and struct ip commented everywhere ), There is the icmp 69 as reply.

I thought when i first tried these "configurations" that these would not cause any difference, but it does. Why ?

Does anyone see what's wrong and how i could fix my issues ? If yes, how ?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you check with a network trace that your packet is really sent and how it looks like? Maybe `s_ping` is declared wrong and has padding bytes that you don't expect?

Comment: @WernerHenze I try pinging myself, and I use tcpdump to see what's my output, compared to the "real" ping it seems ok to me

Comment: Maybe the one who implements the echo reply, send the IP packet buffer instead of Icmp buffer!